# nvcc for Android, arm

Tags: android, cuda, android-ndk

I have a Linux (x64) version of cuda-6.0 with `nvcc` that claims to support `--target-cpu-architecture ARM`. On the other hand, the latest Windows `nvcc` does not recognize ARM. Is this my problem, like I did not install the necessary packages, or does NVIDIA only provide such cross-compiler for Linux hosts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross-compile targets for any given OS are listed in the relevant [getting started documents](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#getting-started-guides).  Refer to tables 1 and 2 in the Windows and Linux documents respectively.

You cannot target ARM from a windows-based CUDA toolkit.